# Excel to SQL formula translate (Counting Week Numbers for custom week start)

Tags: sql-server, excel

Currently I have an Excel spread sheet that uses formula to calculate the "Business Week Number". I want to make a SQL statement that selects where I can pass in a date and will calculate the week number for me (If this is possible)

How the Excel formula works?

- The Business Week always starts on Monday and ends on Sunday
- The year always starts between 27/10 and 02/11 (because of this sometimes the year will have 52weeks and sometimes 53weeks)
- Each business week always has 7 days

If it helps, here how the formula works (formula by cells):

```
Cell C9 =IF(OR(AND(DAY(B9)>26,
   MONTH(B9)=10, WEEKDAY(B9)=2), AND(DAY(B9)<3, MONTH(B9)=11, WEEKDAY(B9=2))), 1, C2+1)

Cell C10 =C9
Cell C11 =C10
Cell C12 =C11
Cell C13 =C12
Cell C14 =C13
Cell C15 =C14
```

From cell C15 the top formula applies again and so on...

[image]
As first week start you can use 29/10/2018

—————————
EDIT:

This is what I have so far but it only works for the first 52 weeks (1st year from start). Does someone knows a solution how to restart the counting once the date comes between the two dates mentioned above but also in the last count I need 7 days counted with the week number.

```
DECLARE @StartDate datetime;
SET @StartDate = '2018-10-29';

DECLARE @DateForCheck datetime;
SET @DateForCheck = '2019-10-27';

SELECT @DateForCheck AS 'Date',
    CASE
        WHEN @DateForCheck < @StartDate THEN 'Only future dates after 27/04/2018 are allowed'
        WHEN @DateForCheck >= @StartDate THEN
            ((DATEDIFF(DAY, @StartDate, @DateForCheck)+7) / 7) END AS 'Business Week Number'
```

The above code gives me output as 52, but if I change the @DateForCheck to '2018-10-28' it gives me 53 (And if the date is between 27/10 and 02/11 I need to restart the counting from 1)

Comment: You say *The year always starts between 27/10 and 02/11*. What determines the exact date on which the new year starts?

Comment: after the previous count of seven days for either the week 52 or 53 depends which year. So lets say, for 2018 there should be 52 weeks and the start of the 53rd is between these dates. That means there will be no 53 but we will start counting for the next year from week 1

Comment: In basic, there will be minimum 52 weeks and maximum 53 weeks each year. So at the start of the 53rd check the first date if it is between 27/10 and 02/11. If yes, start from 1, if no finish counting the 53rd week and then start from 1.

Comment: So in other words, the *Monday* which falls between 27-Oct and 02-Nov defines the first week of the year? For example, for 2019, the first week of the year begins on Mon 28-Oct? For 2020, it begins 02-Nov?

Comment: Sorry for my late comment, newborn at home. But, yes 28th Oct is the start of the year for 2019 and 2nd Nov for 2020.

Comment: Ah, congratulations :). Is it your intention to pre-generate a date table, or are you going to calculate it all on the fly in a function and from first principles? In the former case, you can probably just iterate through all dates from an anchor point, incrementint the week count every 7 days, and resetting the week count and incrementing the year count every time you encounter a Monday within the relevant range 28-Oct/02-Nov, and obviously once this is generated you can simply join onto it. To avoid iterating and calculate it all arithmetically from first principles is vastly more complex.

Comment: I've post my solution bellow, the plan is to make it function as most likely I'll need it very often for statistics and reporting. Thank you for your support.

Comment: If you need it frequently for statistics and reporting, it might be best to pre-generate the table and then just join it on. I'm not the one who has downvoted your answer, but it is truly dreadful haha! If I find time, I will post a better answer.

Comment: Mostly for reporting in SSRS where reports will use it once a day or once a week. When I said I will need it very often, the reports are changed very often with a new requirements (almost every week we have changes in SSRS reports)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Got it finally, if someone has a similar problem I'll post my solution here that works for me. If you have a better solution please post it here.

```
DECLARE @Input datetime;
SET @Input = '2020-11-1';

DECLARE @YearStart datetime;
DECLARE @Mon datetime;

-- FIND WHERE IS MONDAY IN THE SELECTED YEAR INPUT
SET @Mon = CASE
        WHEN DATENAME(WEEKDAY, CONVERT(datetime, CONVERT(NVARCHAR(4), DATEPART(YEAR, @Input)) + '-10-27')) = 'Monday'
            THEN CONVERT(datetime, CONVERT(NVARCHAR(4), DATEPART(YEAR, @Input)) + '-10-27')
        WHEN DATENAME(WEEKDAY, CONVERT(datetime, CONVERT(NVARCHAR(4), DATEPART(YEAR, @Input)) + '-10-28')) = 'Monday'
            THEN CONVERT(datetime, CONVERT(NVARCHAR(4), DATEPART(YEAR, @Input)) + '-10-28')
        WHEN DATENAME(WEEKDAY, CONVERT(datetime, CONVERT(NVARCHAR(4), DATEPART(YEAR, @Input)) + '-10-29')) = 'Monday'
            THEN CONVERT(datetime, CONVERT(NVARCHAR(4), DATEPART(YEAR, @Input)) + '-10-29')
        WHEN DATENAME(WEEKDAY, CONVERT(datetime, CONVERT(NVARCHAR(4), DATEPART(YEAR, @Input)) + '-10-30')) = 'Monday'
            THEN CONVERT(datetime, CONVERT(NVARCHAR(4), DATEPART(YEAR, @Input)) + '-10-30')
        WHEN DATENAME(WEEKDAY, CONVERT(datetime, CONVERT(NVARCHAR(4), DATEPART(YEAR, @Input)) + '-10-31')) = 'Monday'
            THEN CONVERT(datetime, CONVERT(NVARCHAR(4), DATEPART(YEAR, @Input)) + '-10-31')
        WHEN DATENAME(WEEKDAY, CONVERT(datetime, CONVERT(NVARCHAR(4), DATEPART(YEAR, @Input)) + '-11-1')) = 'Monday'
            THEN CONVERT(datetime, CONVERT(NVARCHAR(4), DATEPART(YEAR, @Input)) + '-11-1')
        WHEN DATENAME(WEEKDAY, CONVERT(datetime, CONVERT(NVARCHAR(4), DATEPART(YEAR, @Input)) + '-11-2')) = 'Monday'
            THEN CONVERT(datetime, CONVERT(NVARCHAR(4), DATEPART(YEAR, @Input)) + '-11-2')
    END

-- BASED ON WHERE MONDAY FALLS, SET THE YEAR START
IF @Input >= @Mon
    SET @YearStart = @Mon
ELSE
    SET @YearStart = CASE
                    WHEN DATENAME(WEEKDAY, CONVERT(datetime, CONVERT(NVARCHAR(4), DATEPART(YEAR, @Input) -1) + '-10-27')) = 'Monday'
                        THEN CONVERT(datetime, CONVERT(NVARCHAR(4), DATEPART(YEAR, @Input) -1) + '-10-27')
                    WHEN DATENAME(WEEKDAY, CONVERT(datetime, CONVERT(NVARCHAR(4), DATEPART(YEAR, @Input) -1) + '-10-28')) = 'Monday'
                        THEN CONVERT(datetime, CONVERT(NVARCHAR(4), DATEPART(YEAR, @Input) -1) + '-10-28')
                    WHEN DATENAME(WEEKDAY, CONVERT(datetime, CONVERT(NVARCHAR(4), DATEPART(YEAR, @Input) -1) + '-10-29')) = 'Monday'
                        THEN CONVERT(datetime, CONVERT(NVARCHAR(4), DATEPART(YEAR, @Input) -1) + '-10-29')
                    WHEN DATENAME(WEEKDAY, CONVERT(datetime, CONVERT(NVARCHAR(4), DATEPART(YEAR, @Input) -1) + '-10-30')) = 'Monday'
                        THEN CONVERT(datetime, CONVERT(NVARCHAR(4), DATEPART(YEAR, @Input) -1) + '-10-30')
                    WHEN DATENAME(WEEKDAY, CONVERT(datetime, CONVERT(NVARCHAR(4), DATEPART(YEAR, @Input) -1) + '-10-31')) = 'Monday'
                        THEN CONVERT(datetime, CONVERT(NVARCHAR(4), DATEPART(YEAR, @Input) -1) + '-10-31')
                    WHEN DATENAME(WEEKDAY, CONVERT(datetime, CONVERT(NVARCHAR(4), DATEPART(YEAR, @Input) -1) + '-11-1')) = 'Monday'
                        THEN CONVERT(datetime, CONVERT(NVARCHAR(4), DATEPART(YEAR, @Input) -1) + '-11-1')
                    WHEN DATENAME(WEEKDAY, CONVERT(datetime, CONVERT(NVARCHAR(4), DATEPART(YEAR, @Input) -1) + '-11-2')) = 'Monday'
                        THEN CONVERT(datetime, CONVERT(NVARCHAR(4), DATEPART(YEAR, @Input) -1) + '-11-2')
                END

--CALCULATE THE BUSINESS WEEK NUMBER
SELECT (DATEDIFF(DAY, @YearStart, @Input)+7) / 7 AS 'Business Week Number'
```

The trick was first to see where Monday falls under the chosen year input, then check if the input is before that and calculate the YearStart for the correct date. At the end just calculate how many weeks has passed since.